# Ansible adhoc command

Tags: ansible

I am executing ansible adhoc command

```
ansible hosts -m shell -a 'df -P | awk '0+$5 >=30 {print}''
#ERROR! Missing target hosts
```

The single quotes that we use for awk print is conflicting with the `-a` `''` command that we use.

I tried below formats no luck.
I believe there is way to escape `'`

```
ansible hosts -m command -a 'df -P|awk '0+$5 >=30 {print}''
ansible hosts -m command -a "df -P|awk '0+$5 >=30 {print}'"
ansible hosts -m command -a 'df -P|awk "0+$5 >=30 {print}"'
```

Anyone has tried this before.

Comment: No luck, I tried all 3 perm/combo.

Comment: Is the group 'hosts' in your inventory?  Do you have hosts defined?  Keep in mind that the 'command' module is not going to work, you must use the shell for your command since  you have a `|` pipe..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `"` with awk and `'` for `-a`option, like below:

```
ansible hosts -m shell -a 'df -P | awk "0+$5 >=30 {print}"'
```